# WebParts with JavaScript don't work with managed path

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, managed-path

I developed a SharePoint 2010 WebParts with JavaScript and CSS(inside a module). I haven't problem on development environment but in production environment.

In production environment I have a WebApplication `(http://productionapplication/)` with managed path "corp" `(http://productionapplication/corp/)` and a SiteCollection "product"  `(http://productionapplication/corp/product)`.

GET HTTP request fail for my JavaScript and CSS on loading my WebParts. Script and CSS are correctly deployed inside `"http://productionapplication/corp/product/MyDocumentLibrary/"`

How can I resolve my problem?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: How did you reference the static resources from within the webpart?

Comment: Hi, I add simply code like that inside WebPart: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're on SharePoint Foundation (thus you cannot use the $SPUrl expression), I would suggest that you resort to some classic ASP.Net tricks to workaround your issue:

Add a runat="server" and id attributes to the link element

```
<link id="css1" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="" />
```

Within the Page_Load method, add this code:

```
css1.Attributes["href"] = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css");
```

Comment: Hi Mazzotti, I try your solutions as soon as possibile. Thanks

Comment: Hi Mazzotti, now my application work correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @ilMattion glad I helped

Answer (score 1):

Try the `SPUrl` token:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href='<% $SPUrl:~site/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css %>' />
```

If that doesn't work, try the full relative path to you managed path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="corp/product/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css" />
```

Comment: Hi, I added your code but I have this error: _Literal expressions like `'<% $SPUrl:~site/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$SPUrl:~site/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css%>" /> instead.`_

Comment: @Marco try what the error message is suggesting. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href='<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$SPUrl:~site/MyDocumentLibrary/Css/example.css%>" />' />

Comment: Thanks, now I have this error: _The expression prefix 'SPUrl' was not recognized.  Please correct the prefix or register the prefix in the <expressionBuilders> section of configuration_. I'm looking for this problem.

Comment: @marco sorry, I noticed only now that you're on SP Foundation, where SPUrl is not supported

Comment: Sorry, I not specified that. Now I try second solution.